# Bootstrap put image above center text

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have the following code:

```
   <div class="h-100 row align-items-center">
     <div class="col text-center">
       <div class="container">
       <h1> Applying to medicine? We can help.</h1>
       <button type="button" onclick="location.href='about.html'" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg">More information</button>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

This just puts in the center of my page the text and the button defined as above. Now I have a lot of space left above of this structure, and I want to put an image just above this text, still centered both horizontally and vertically.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HTML `img` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/html/element/img).

```html
<div class="h-100 row align-items-center">
    <div class="col text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
            <h1> Applying to medicine? We can help.</h1>
            <button type="button" onclick="location.href='about.html'" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg">More information</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Bootstrap imports: -->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```